# ValueError: Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

I am trying to calculate `roc_auc_score`, but I am getting following error.

```
"ValueError: Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified"
```

My code snippet is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
y_scores=np.array([ 0.63, 0.53, 0.36, 0.02, 0.70 ,1 , 0.48, 0.46, 0.57])
y_true=np.array(['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'])
roc_auc_score(y_true, y_scores)
```

Please tell me what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You only need to change `y_true`so it looks like this:

```
y_true=np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

**Explanation:**
If you take a look to what `roc_auc_score` functions does in [https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.15.X/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py) you will see that `y_true` is evaluated as follows:

```
classes = np.unique(y_true)
if (pos_label is None and not (np.all(classes == [0, 1]) or
 np.all(classes == [-1, 1]) or
 np.all(classes == [0]) or
 np.all(classes == [-1]) or
 np.all(classes == [1]))):
    raise ValueError("Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified")
```

At the moment of the execution `pos_label` is `None`, but as long as your are defining `y_true` as an array of characters the `np.all` are always `false` and as all of them are negated then the if condition is `true`and the exception is raised.

Comment: Seems like the file was deleted a long time ago and its no longer working in current version, I have updated the link to an older version

Answer (score 0):

We have problem in 
`y_true=np.array(['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'])`
Convert values of y_true to Boolean

```
y_true= '1' <= y_true
print(y_true) # [False  True False False  True  True  True  True  True]
```