# SVC model - ValueError: Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Using Python 2.7, I am trying to carry out grid searches for AUC and accuracy scores for a SVC model. I get the error as outlined below.

Attempted to troubleshoot to no avail.

```
clf = SVC(kernel = 'rbf')
parameter_grid = [
  {'C': [0.1, 1, 10, 50, 100, 400], 
   'gamma': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]}
]

clf_stand_acc = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid = parameter_grid)
clf_stand_acc.fit(X_train, y_train) 
y_predict_auc = clf_stand_acc.predict(X_test)


clf_stand_auc = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid = parameter_grid, scoring = 'roc_auc')
clf_stand_auc.fit(X_train, y_train) 
y_predict_auc = clf_stand_auc.predict(X_test)

print('Test of AUC: ', roc_auc_score(y_test, y_predict_auc))
```

Expected something like the following output.
Test set AUC: 0.9993784757585

Snippet of the actual output below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-ef06600e0bf8> in <module>()
     19 # Generate an auc object with the classifier and grid parameters.
     20 clf_stand_auc = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid = parameter_grid, scoring = 'roc_auc')
---> 21 clf_stand_auc.fit(X_train, y_train)
     22 y_predict_auc = clf_stand_auc.predict(X_test)
     23 

ValueError: Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified
```

Comment: Well, is your target binary or not? Please show a sample of your `y`.

Comment: I rechecked my feature recoding and the class label was 1 and 2 rather than 1 and 0 respectively, problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As this answer goes(possible duplicate):
[ValueError: Data is not binary and pos_label is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401112/valueerror-data-is-not-binary-and-pos-label-is-not-specified)

Your y_train, should look like this:

```
y_train=np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I don't know what your y values look like, however this should help you: [one hot encode a binary value in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516456/one-hot-encode-a-binary-value-in-numpy)